# How do I change the text style of a spinner?

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I'm creating a spinner in my layout xml files and setting an string array to this spinner. 
If I change the textstyle of the spinner the text is not affected by the changes.

I read in the googlegroups that a spinner has no text and therefore the textstyle can not be changed and I have to change the style of the textview that is shown in the spinner. But how can I do that. Preferably in my xml file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you create the Adapter that backs the Spinner you can set a layout for the spinner item.

```
spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.id.some_text_view));
```

You can style some_text_view the way you want.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/some_text_view" android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: and there is no possibility to do this within the xml file? If I set the items in the xml I do not need to set an ArrayAdapter myself...

Comment: If you use android:entries then internally it creates an ArrayAdapter with android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item as the layout and no you can't change that layout since it is an internal to android.

Answer (score 30):

As my predecessor specified, you can't do it on the main XML layout file where the Spinner component is.

And the answer above is nice, but if we want to use Google's best practices, like you know... to use styles for everything... you could do it in 3 'easy' steps as follows:

**Step 1:** You need an extra file under your layout folder with the look for the Spinner's items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/textViewSpinnerItem" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    style="@style/SpinnerTextViewItem"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Name this file: spinner_item_text.xml

**Step 2:** Then, on your Activity Class when you are filling the Spinner with an array of items:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, R.layout.spinner_item_text, items);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Note that the **R.layout.spinner_item_text** resource is in your own R's file.

**Step 3:** Under your values folder, create or use (you might have one already) the file  styles.xml. The style entry needed should look like this one:

```
<style name="SpinnerTextViewItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView" >
    <item name="android:textSize" >8dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle" >bold</item>
</style>
```

And that's it!

So far it has been really, really handy to put all about text sizes, styles, colors, etc... on a styles.xml file so it's easy to maintain.

Comment: Adding `<item name="android:textAppearance"> @android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem </item>` (or whatever theme-appropriate style) to `SpinnerTextViewItem` will make sure the font color is visible against the spinner's background.

Comment: Nice implementation, but you can actually do it all in XML. See @Cyril REAL's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8871505/293280

Comment: What if I want to do it just to the top element?

Answer (score 23):

### Via XML Only

As a follow-up to @Cyril REAL's excellent answer, here is a thorough implementation of how to style your Spinners **just** through XML if you're populating your Spinner via `android:entries`.

The above answers work if you're creating your *Spinner* via code but if you're setting your Spinner entries via XML, i.e. using `android:entries`, then you can adjust the text size and other attributes with the following two theme settings:

#### In your res/values/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

        <!-- For the resting Spinner style -->
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">
            @style/spinnerItemStyle
        </item> 

        <!-- For each individual Spinner list item once clicked on -->
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
            @style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle
        </item>

    </style>

    <style name="spinnerItemStyle">
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

    <style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
        <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: For AppCompat theme just remove `android:` like this `<item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>`

Answer (score 9):

Actually you can customize spinner's text by xml.

In your own style, define a :

```
<item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/yourStyleForSpinnerItem</item>
```

and define this style also :

```
<style name="yourStyleForSpinnerItem">

  // Stuff you want for the item style.

</style>
```

When you instantiate the spinner's adapter in the java code, you can use the default android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item

Comment: This works for me, and is much easier than having to go through and define all the adapters in code rather than xml.

Comment: can you please explain it more? Where should the 'item' be defined? And where can I set the style in the spinner?

Comment: android:spinnerItemStyle is attribute of theme. This attribute is a reference to spinner item style. So if you put this item to your custom theme that you use for your app, it will be used. Theme is a style typically stored themes.xml as descendant of some default android theme. For more info go here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: To customize the actual spinner list item, use **`android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle`** instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want such workarounds, there's a simple way. Get the textview from the spinner and change its parameters:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) spin.getSelectedView();
tv.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD); //to make text bold
tv.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT); //to make text normal
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want just change background of popup View in spinner, call this method:

```
spinner.setPopupBackgroundResource(R.color.pa_md_white);
```