# Android spinner custom style for spinnerDropDownItemStyle not working

Tags: android, android-styles

I have added some custom style to Android spinner. I am trying to have prompt small but drop down items little big. My code looks like below :

**theme.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
.
.
.
 <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/spinnerItemStyle</item>
 <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle</item>
</style>
.
.
.
<style name="spinnerItemStyle">
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
<style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
        <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
 </style>
```

Now I am able to set the `spinnerItemStyle` properly, but some how style for `spinnerDropDownItemStyle` is not having any effect, its not working. Any clues why is this happening ? I want my drop-down items with big text size than that of prompt item.

Comment: clarify your ques a little bit. Do you want your dropdown items to be customized??

Comment: Don't go with spinner for this. Create your layout to be visible. On click of that layout open AlertDialog with List containing your big layout!

Comment: @Dr. aNdRO thanks for your advice, its good one, but do you have any clue why above styling is not working ?

Comment: @pcj any luck figuring this out?  Same problem here.

Comment: @ Andy Dennie, Nope. What I was trying, not worked as it was expected. Then I prefer Dr. anDRO's approach.

Answer (score 8):

This question is old but was not correct answered.

Support Library has a custom support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@android:id/text1"
      style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

Therefore, to make your custom style work, you must override a local **spinnerDropDownItemStyle** (without the android: prefix) in your app style.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/TextViewSpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/TextViewSpinnerDropDownItem</item>
    <!-- Override the dropdown item in support library -->
    <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/TextViewSpinnerDropDownItem</item>
</style>
```

Change whatever you want:

```
<style name="TextViewSpinnerItem" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1</item>
</style>

<style name="TextViewSpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1</item>
</style>
```

Now, all your simple spinner dropdowns will look exactly the same.

Comment: I agree that your answer would be better, but with your method I have not been able to change dropdown item height, so I ended up with Riga solution

Comment: I had hope in this method, but when I override spinnerDropDownItemStyle, it just makes my drop down items disappear.

Answer (score 3):

Found this article that explains how to do it:
[How to change a Spinner text size, color or overall style](http://www.broculos.net/2013/09/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-color.html)

You need to create a style for the input item and the dropdown items and add them.

Customize spinner input:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#ff0000" />
```

Add style:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Customize dropdown list items:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColor="#aa66cc"/>
```

Add style to spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's old question, but I recently ran into same problem. The solution was to remove `android:` from `<item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">`

According to Roman_D's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205387/how-do-i-change-the-text-style-of-a-spinner#comment66777739_21174361), it has something to do with AppCompat Theme.