# Selected item in spinner is white in android versions lowwer or equal to 23

Tags: android-spinner, android-theme

In my activity inside oncreate I instantiate and set adapter to the Spinner like this 
...

```
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this
            , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, members);
            arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            memberSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

In the xml i declare spinner like this
...

```
        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp_members"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

I have this base theme for application which i suspect is the cause of this

```
       <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

In android api level 24 and above which i have tested the image is like this..
[Image in android 7 device](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MemAWTCNPw1MRZ-ezYsaxjio0SLJleM7)
And below something like this...
[Image in android 5 device](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11O9HX51tntnsxaUNHf3EBfLe5XrfxJMF)

PLEASE HOW CAN I MAKE SURE THE SELECTED SPINNER ITEM IS ALWAYS BLACK IN COLOR. (So that it is always easily readable)

Comment: Please I have looked at almost all the spinner related question and tried solutions like using a custom layout for spinner item or drop down list. But to no avail. I am not familiar with themes and how to tweak them to suite my needs. I just want the spinner to look presentable in all versions

Comment: please look perfectly two images. background color change so i think you use different different theme for both.

Comment: I did not fully understand the question, for is the problem with the spinner?

Comment: @AnteGeminithe don't know if the problem is with spinner or the theme which is used in the application. But if you view those images i shared in the question you see clearly that in one device the selected spinner item is white while in another it is black. Yet both devices are running thesame app. Now my worry is that the spinner would not readable with it appears white

Comment: @Ali please explain more

Answer (score 0):

You can define inside your theme style for selected spinner value and for values in drop down list.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="spinnerItemStyle">@style/spinnerText</item>
    <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/spinnerText</item>
</style>
<style name="spinnerText">
    <item name="textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

More on this in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21174361/1573414

Comment: this the error i got when I tried implementing the code: style attribute 'attr/spinnerItemStyle (aka com.example.android.hubert:attr/spinnerItemStyle)' not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: style attribute 'attr/spinnerItemStyle (aka com.example.android.hubert:attr/spinnerItemStyle)' not found., sources=[/home/hubert/Hubert/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

Comment: I added "android" to all the item names as in <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle".. and it built and ran successfully but the issue of having white text  in some devices persists